# Ngrok not forwarding POST request data

Tags: localhost, http-post, webhooks, ngrok

I'm exposing my local server to the internet using ngrok for which I wrote the following code:

```
const ngrok = require('ngrok')

ngrok.connect({
    proto: 'http', 
    addr: 3000, 
    authtoken: '<my-token>',
}).then(url => console.log(url))
```

The trigger for the api endpoint/webhook is a POST request which sends some data in request object. When I visit http://localhost:4040 to inspect the logs of the original request, I can see the data required by my local application. But maybe ngrok modifies the original request object and doesn't forward the original POST data to my application.
Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing the data in the localhost:4040 logs, it's hitting your app.

We don't drop/modify fields or parameters from the requests unless you tell us to.

~ an ngrok employee

Comment: But when I log request body object on my local server, I get empty object

Comment: on my local server, I get hit but request.body is empty.

Comment: Solved! It was header content type error. Request was not getting parsed by express JS

Comment: how did you solve it? what did you add?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed mine by adding this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

Answer (score 0):

for Express.js I found this decision:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

thanks philip-adamson and Jeremy Caney

Comment: If you're not providing your own answer nor adding anything to other answers please refrain from posting it as an answer. A command would be better suited to thank people. Once you earn enough reputation you'll be able to leave comments